# Ricatti differential equation $y'=-13(x-y^{2})$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

$$y'=-13(x-y^{2})$$

I'm a beginner. I know, that this is a kind of Riccati equation, but is it possible to solve it with only simple methods? 
Thank you

p.s. I know nothing about Bessel functions. Please, be explicit

Comment: Please show us what you have attempted so far, and where exactly you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The derivation in the first section of [Ricatti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) uses only elementary but judiciously chosen substitutions (with malice aforethought).

$$
y' = -13 x + 0 y + 13 y^2\\
q_0 = -13 x\\
q_1 = 0\\
q_2 = 13\\
S = q_2 q_0 = -169 x\\
R = q_1 + \frac{q_2'}{q_2} = 0 + \frac{0}{13} = 0\\
v = 13 y\\
v' = v^2 + 0 v + (-169 x)\\
v = \frac{-u'}{u}\\
u'' - 169 x u = 0
$$

You solve for $u$ and then plug in to get $v$ and from there $y$.

How do you solve a differential equation like

$$
y'' - x*y = 0
$$

It is not an elementary function. It is the [Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).

So getting

$$
u'' - 169 x u = 0\\
t = A x\\
\tilde{u}(t) = u(\frac{t}{A})\\
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\tilde{u} (t) = \frac{1}{A^2} u'' (\frac{t}{A})\\
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\tilde{u} (t) = \frac{1}{A^2} 169 \frac{t}{A} \tilde{u} (t)\\
$$

Let $A^3=169$, $A=13^{2/3}$ to give

$$
\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\tilde{u} (t) - t \tilde{u} (t) = 0\\
\tilde{u}(t) = Airy(t)\\
u(x) = \tilde{u}(Ax) = Airy(Ax)
$$

Use that to get back to $v$ and $y$.